cron fails to launch @reboot script
Running 6.8.0-45-generic, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I have a bash script, it launches in Terminal with
/path-to-script/script.sh 

I want to have it launch on reboot, so in my crontab I have
@reboot /path-to-script/script.sh

But nothing happens, the script does not run on reboot.
syslog shows:
cron[1474]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)

So . . . any help with debugging will be appreciated. Thank you!

I would always have scripts output to a log so you can easily see if there are any messages/errors, e.g. @reboot /path-to-script/script.sh > /path-to-logs/script.log 2>&1 The usual culprit in these situations is that your shell environment vars etc when you run in terminal will not be the same as when cron runs the script. But without seeing the script it's impossible to say.

Thank you, good idea. I find in the log an issue on Line 17 of my script: -ne 0:0:3
/home/kpov-tech/Desktop/scripts/KPOV_Audio_Processing_Loader.sh: 17: let: not found

Thank you, good idea! The log file shows:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
There are other issues listed after this one, unclear whether fixing this first issue will clear the following ones until this first one is addressed. Important to remind that the script runs fine when launched via Terminal.

See cron command not working for let: not found … if your script requires display and audio then those might not be available until after user login when the user session gets created.

Oh, okay. Yes, the script launches programs that require display and audio (jack audio, raysession, and some other swell bits). It was my hope that I could set it up to automatically launch the script at reboot, rather than manually (it is a headless machine in a remote location), but if it can't be done, then it can't be done. Thank you!

Oh wait -- Ubuntu's Startup Applications feature does the job quite nicely. Thanks all for looking at this!

If the machine is set to automatic login, then you could  use a user service or a startup application to run your script and run it with /bin/bash for Bash specific commands like let to work ... You also could, probably, get away with just adding a delay to the beginning of your script like sleep 2m (2 minutes) and run it from user (not root's) crontab using @reboot ... Speaking Ubuntu of course :-)
